# Super Resolution of a single image C/C++ Source code?

Tags: c++, c, image, image-resizing

I am trying to build an application that uses Super Resolution to upsample/upscale a single low resolution image. Such algorithms are called Single Image Super Resolution. I am looking for any existing C/C++ based implementations of this algorithm out there for quick prototyping. If you have come across the code, can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple Google Search (`super resolution c++`) lead to [this](https://github.com/Palethorn/SuperResolution) github repository. It seems to be what you're looking for.